# is it possible to have a selector case insensitive

Tags: cytoscape.js

Currently I have a search on name feature implemented using a selector:

```
cy.nodes(`[name *= '${pattern}']`);
```

It works fine, but it is case sensitive.
Is it possible to define a selector case insensitive ?

The solution I plan if there is no choice is to implement it manually, with a forEach on every node, and a function which makes the test.

Comment: Attribute-selectors can be made case-insensitive with the `i` flag before the closing `]`: `[name="foo"i]`.

Comment: When I use this selector, as suggested:

`cy.nodes([name *= '${pattern}i']);`

I get every node as a result, even nodes which does not match the pattern.

Comment: The `i` go outside the quotes, e.g. `cy.nodes[name*='pattern'i]`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the issue with :

```
const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');
const result = cyRef.current.nodes().filter((ele) => regex.test(ele.data('name') as string));
```